# Excel weekends conditional formatting

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use conditional formatting to highlight only weekends and public holidays using this example [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2013/04/04/using-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-dates-in-excel/#:~:text=Highlighting%20holidays&text=Again%2C%20open%20the%20menu%20Conditional,month%20is%20greater%20than%201.&text=Then%2C%20in%20the%20dialog%20box,select%20the%20range%20B4%3AAF11](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2013/04/04/using-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-dates-in-excel/#:%7E:text=Highlighting%20holidays&text=Again%2C%20open%20the%20menu%20Conditional,month%20is%20greater%20than%201.&text=Then%2C%20in%20the%20dialog%20box,select%20the%20range%20B4%3AAF11).
but it won't work.. cells is highlighted but it's not weekends. I'm unable to get holiday to be highlight too.

Cells is also highlighted based on the absent reason such as AL, MC etc which is working.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you want `=WEEKDAY(c$4,2)` standard is Sunday through Saturday, the 2 makes it Monday through Sunday.  also i think you want to lock row 4 not column c hence `c$4`

Comment: If you want to highlight both weekends and holidays then use a formula like this in conditional formatting this should work for you `=(SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Cell_Reference,Holiday_List_Absolute_Range))))+(WEEKDAY(Cell_Referene,2)>5)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NETWORKDAYS` to check for both: weekend and holidays.

`=NETWORKDAYS(C$4,C$4,Holiday!$F$3:$F$15)=0`

Usually you use the formula to get the net workdays between two dates omitting weekends - and if supplied as third parameter - holidays.

In this case we check for only one day - if it is a saturday, sunday or holiday 0 is returned otherwise 1 (= 1 net workday).

Be careful to fix row 4 but to keep the column relative - hence C$4 - as InjuredCoding already wrote.

The screenshot shows the concept - try to adapt it to your environment:
[image]

Comment: It's not working for me.. does the priority matter for these formulas? i have other condition to highlight the cells based on data entered which is working. https://imgur.com/a/H4hfWgP

Comment: What happens, if you paste the formula in cell C6? It should show 1.

Comment: It shows no value.. https://imgur.com/a/Tc9kNeZ

Comment: I added a screenshot showing how it works - could it be that your reference to the holidays range is wrong?